# Extract required text and number from image capturing

Tags: android, text, numbers

I need to extract text and numbers from captured image. For this I am using this  [library](https://github.com/bieliaievays/Tess-two_example) but I did not get exact data what I scanned, some data missing or dummy text added to captured data and also I want to show the data of same order, what I have in image. Here I am showing the example image to scan data. Here it has 3 row of data and below the rows date but when I scan it some numbers are replaced by letters and special characters. Is there better library or better procedure, Please suggest me to get exact data.[image]

Comment: Welcome to OCR world :) recognition is not easy and you have to have  very good quality scans for close to 100% result; if no current library does that you have to write your own recognition logic

Comment: is there any good recognition libraries

Comment: sorry have not done anything last 5 years on this - no recommendations, but try googling for other options than you are using now

Comment: but real recommendation is to have source as good as possible with 1000+ dpi any library should be good :)